# Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am using SQl-server 2012 and this code is inside in a Stored Procedure.

These are my SQL queries.I want to execute "Insert" query when "Update" query not executed.
If Update query executed,then insert query should not be executed.

```
Update tblStock Set Balance= Balance +  @ReduceRawQty 
    Where LocCode=@LocCode 
    AND ItemCode=@rawitemcode 
    and CostPrice=@rawcostprice

Insert Into tblStock(LocCode, ItemCode, CostPrice, Balance,Transfer,PCode)
    Values(@LocCode,@rawitemcode,@RawCostPrice,@RawQty,0,@PCode)
```

Is there any method to do this ,please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql) to see how many rows were affected by the UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE ...

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    INSERT ...
```

Alternatively you can use EXISTS to check for a row first and decide which operation to perform:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblStock WHERE LocCode=@LocCode AND ItemCode=@rawitemcode and CostPrice=@rawcostprice)
    UPDATE ...
ELSE
    INSERT ...
```